# Can I put a timeframe on a Magento Category?

Tags: category

I want to add a "New" subcategory to each of my main product categories.  When I enter a new product into my store I would like to set a date for how long it appears in that category.  Then on the date expiration its now longer "New."  Is that a default feature or extension purchase?  Or code myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default feature that does what you describe. There is a new product widget in Magento that depends on the product setting "Set Product as New from Date" and "Set Product as New to Date" in the general settings tab. You could extend this to take category into account.

There are also various extensions listed on Magento Connect that do this to varying degrees.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710989/how-to-show-new-products-from-specific-category-in-magento) shows a method on getting the product list based on those dates and category id based on a similar question.